# The convex hull of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

For a matrix $A = (a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, denote
\begin{equation*}
    \| A\|_{b, c} := \big\| (\| a_1\|_b, \ldots, \| a_n\|_b)^{\top} \big\|_c.
\end{equation*}
where $\| \cdot \|_c$ denote the norm of a vector. i.e. for a vector $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^m$,
\begin{equation*}
    \|x\|_c := \big( |x_1|^c + \cdots + |x_m|^c \big)^{1 / c},
\end{equation*}
and $\| x \|_{\infty} := \max_{j = 1, \ldots, m} |x_j|$. Now suppose $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, does the following relationship hold?
\begin{equation*}
    \big\{ A^{\top} b : b \in V \big\} = \big\{ \| A^{\top} \|_{1, \infty} b : b \in \operatorname{conv} (-V \cup V)\big\},
\end{equation*}
where $\operatorname{conv}$ is the convex hull of a set.

Comment: What are $\| \cdot \|_b$ and $\| \cdot \|_c$?

Comment: @WillM. I just add the definition of $\ | \cdot \|_c$. Thanks for your reminder.